# Loading local HTML with local Javascript Sources in a WKWebView (iOS, Swift)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to load a local html file in a WKWebView for a iOS app (Swift 4.2). Unfortunately, this local file contains javascript code that does not seem to be executed.

Below is this html file (taken from https://www.verovio.org/tutorial.xhtml?id=topic00):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Verovio Hello World! example</title>
        <script src="verovio-toolkit.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World!
        <div id="svg_output"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var vrvToolkit = new verovio.toolkit();
            $.ajax({
               url: "Beethoven_StringQuartet_op.18_no.2.mei"
               , dataType: "text"
               , success: function(data) {
               var svg = vrvToolkit.renderData(data);
               $("#svg_output").html(svg);
               }
               });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And below the view controller file written in swift:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "html")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
    }
}
```

Files are local under "Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources" in the project properties. I also tried to put them in a directory but without any success. Below the file organization inside the project.

[image]

**EDIT:** When I change the url in the html file from `Beethoven.mei` to `https://www.verovio.org/gh-tutorial/mei/Beethoven_StringQuartet_op.18_no.2.mei` (same file but on Verovio's website), anything works good!!

So:

- Local .js resources work fine
- The issue comes from jquery not able to load local text file

Any idea on how to make jquery able to load the local file?

Thank you!

M.

Answer (score 1):

First check your `index.html` file has scr path for js. if like below, that means js files contain in js folder. so you need to add reference to that folder while add to project.

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

then get the main resource path like below

```
let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/\(folderName)/\(fileName)"
print("path:=",path )
```

after that load that file to webView

```
do {
    let contents =  try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
    let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
} catch {
    print ("File HTML error")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue seems to come from jquery, see my edit. Thanks again!

Comment: @Maxime Now you can try with let path = Bundle.main.resourcePath! + "/html/index.html"

Comment: I tested just to be sure I didn't miss anything, but it does not solve the problem, as explained in my edit. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414973-loadfileurl), `loadFileURL` does this:

> If `readAccessURL` references a single file, only that file may be loaded by WebKit. If `readAccessURL` references a directory, files inside that file may be loaded by WebKit.

The `url` you got is a url of a file, namely the HTML file. You need the url of the directory. You can do this by calling `deletingLastPathComponent`:

```
webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the issue seems to come from jquery, see my edit. I tried your idea, without success unfortunately :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loadHTMLString` method to load the HTML, as below:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "html")!
do {
    let html = try String(contentsOf: url)
    webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
} catch ....
```

The baseURL point to your app directory in file system. You can write in the `src` property of the `script` tag relative location that is interpreted as relative to baseURL.